# p:calendar does not work

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, calendar

I have a very strange problem regarding `<p:calendar>` component. I have a calendar in a `<p:panelGrid>` (see below), but when I open my page, calendar is not opened when clicked on a "input box" like it should.

```
<p:panelGrid>                           
    <p:calendar value="#{backingBean.date}" />
</p:panelGrid>
```

Of course, date attribute is in my backing bean:

```
private Date date;

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}
```

I just don't know what to do to make it work. One more thing: there are problems with a ~` too. Just cannot click on it to select value.

PS: Using PF 5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the cause of my problem. With my JS validation function, i tried to validate a component with id, that didn't exist. That's why my other components were unresponsive.

Should have thought about it before...

Comment: So you should post code as much as needed in the next time.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there is a `<h:form>` in your page. Generally we specify

```
<p:calendar id="c1" pattern="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" timeZone="IST" 
      value="#{backingBean.date}" showOn="button"/>
```

Checkout [Primeface-caledar showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/calendar.xhtml) for more calendar examples

Answer (score 1):

could you try below code

```
<p:panelGrid columns="1">                          
            <p:calendar value="#{backingBean.date}" />
        </p:panelGrid>
```

or

```
 <p:panelGrid >                          
    <p:row>
        <p:column>
          <p:calendar value="#{backingBean.date}" />
        </p:column>
  </p:row>
</p:panelGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
imports: [
. . .
BrowserAnimationsModule,
. . .
],
. . .
})

in app.module.ts in your project

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).